Correct handling of view change in TGrid
In the TGrid registry I have a BLOB SQL column that I display in TGrid as ImageStyle. Everything works fine, there are no errors.
However, in TGrid I need to change the color of the rows. Selected row - color1, remaining rows - color2. And this is where my problems begin. I couldn't find a simple way to solve my problem, so I started adding lines of code. first I removed problems with coloring, then problems arose with photos not being visible in the registry. Currently, I have the effect I wanted (there are colors and photos), but after scrolling down the lines, the program crashes with the error "Access violation at address 00F3C2D7 in module 'Katalog_klockow_21.exe'. Read of address 0000000C.".
I tried debugging, but I am unable to locate which line the error occurs on. Event
OnDrawColumnCell causes it to run as soon as you hover the cursor over the slider, so I can't even move it.
I would like to point out that as long as I did not modify the color, the registry worked without errors and the photos were displayed correctly.
I am asking for advice on how I should deal with the seemingly simple color change.
My code:

private
    { Private declarations }
    FSelectedRow: Integer;

procedure TZ.RejestrCellClick(const Column: TColumn; const Row: Integer);
begin
  Rejestr.SelectRow(Row);
  FSelectedRow := Row;
  Rejestr.Repaint;  // Odśwież grid, aby ponownie narysować komórki
end;

procedure TZ.RejestrDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
begin
    UstawWygladRejestru  (Sender, Canvas, Column, Bounds, Row, Value,State, FSelectedRow);
end;


procedure TZ.UstawWygladRejestru (Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates; Wiersz: Integer);
begin

//exit;

var  Bitmap: TBitmap;

begin
  if Row = Wiersz then
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Bisque
  else
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Beige;

  Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1);

  if Column is TImageColumn then
    begin

      if Value.IsType<TBitmap> then
      begin
        Bitmap := Value.AsType<TBitmap>;

        Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, RectF(0, 0, Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height),
                          Bounds, 1, True);

      end;
    end
  else
    begin
      Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
      Canvas.FillText(Bounds, Value.ToString, False, 1, [], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Center);
    end;
end;

 i

So far, I've been focusing on finding the simplest solution. The moment I found it, it turned out that I had the "Acces Violaion..." error.

What happens when you step through the code in the debugger? Which line specifically is causing the AV? What is the complete, exact AV message? (The addresses in that message contain information that is useful, but only if you can see them.) When asking for help here, please be very specific and add all the details, whether they mean anything to you or not. Also, you need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue - that would mean the entire procedure, not just some of the lines out of context and missing variable declarations.

You may want to change your if Value.IsType<TBitmap> then to if Value.IsType<TBitmap>(False) then. Notice additional parameter.  According to System.Rtti.TValue.IsType documentation the default value for the mentioned optional parameter is True . So if nothing is assigned to the value the function seems to always return true as a result. ...

... Perhaps you may want to use System.Rtti.TValue.TryCast as this function automatically checks if the Value can be converted to desired type.

Thank you. Adding the default value (false) solved the problem.
By the way, I want to make sure. Isn't there really a more elegant solution to coloring the registry? I only wanted to change the color, and I also have to write support for photos, text, photo scaling...
